# What does ${var,,} mean in Bash?

Tags: bash

example:

```
a=$( printf "%X" 10 )
b=${a,,}
```

anyone knows what is the difference between the value for variable `a` and variable `b`? what the purpose of the second expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ a=$(printf "%X" 10) # assign the HEX conversion value in upper case.
$ echo "${a}" # Print the value
A
$ echo "${a,,}"  # Parameter expansion to bring everything to lowercase
a
```

Instead of assigning `b=${a,,}`, you can do,

```
$ b=$(printf "%x" 10)
$ echo "$b"
a
```

[Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

[Printf command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)